# controller as in with AngularJS form

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller

I am using AngularJS `controller as`, but I fail to correctly define scope for functions in the controller.

```html
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController as myc">
  <form method="post" name="myc.form" ng-init="fetch()" ng-submit="update()">
    <textarea rows="4" class="form-control" id="text" ng-model="lmc.news.text"></textarea>
  </form>
</div>
```

anf the javascript

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyController', function($http){

    this.fetch = function(){
         $http({
            method: 'get',
            url: 'get.php'
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
           this.news = response.data;
        });
    };
```

I guess the `this` in `fetch` method is not appropriate but I don't understand how to do it.

Comment: use '{{  }}' to bind value of function name in angularjs

Comment: shouldn't it be `ng-init="myc.fetch()"`?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot "call" controller in ng-init and ng-submit:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController as myc">
 <form method="post" name="myc.form" ng-init="myc.fetch()" ng-submit="myc.update()">
<textarea rows="4" class="form-control" id="text" ng-model="lmc.news.text"></textarea>
</form>
</div>
```

I think your problem is that.

Comment: It was half the issue.

Comment: see the answer above

Answer (score 0):

There was 2 issues:
As @Schwarz54 and @user2718281 pointed, one must use `ng-init="myc.fetch()"`.

The other isssue, is that the this in the init method is not referring to the same scope.

This works:

```
app.controller('MyController', function($http){

    var that = this;

    this.fetch = function(){
        $http({
            method: 'get',
            url: 'get.php'
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            that.news = response.data;
        });
    };
};
```